# Нужно сделать таблицу на html

Tags: html, table

Всем привет. Нужно сверстать такую таблицу на чистом html.
[image: Фото]

Когда доходжу до обединения строк для 6ки, таблица уменьшается.
Вот мой код

```
<table class="another_table">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td rowspan="5">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="4">3</td>
    <td rowspan="4">6</td>
</tr>
```

Очень благодарен за подсказку:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, всё отлично выводится, возможно, забыли размеры указать?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" width='600' height='600'>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='3' align="center">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">2</td>
            <td rowspan="5" align="center">4</td>
            <td align="center">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" align="center">3</td>
            <td rowspan="4" align="center">6</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Да, я немного недоглядел с селектором, спасибо:)

Comment: Рад помочь. Удачи:)